# Java FTP upload creates an empty file

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

When I try to upload a simple text file with the Apache Commons `FTPClient` and this code:

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
int reply;

// connect
try {

    ftp.connect(serverAdd);
    ftp.login(username,password);
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
        System.out.println("Connected Success..");

        // upload file
        try {
            String fileDir = "testfile.txt";
            FileInputStream in = null;         
            in = new FileInputStream(fileDir);       
            ftp.storeFile(fileDir,in);
            System.out.println("File upload complete..");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        ftp.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected..");

    }else {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed..");
        ftp.disconnect();
    }    

} catch (SocketException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

A file gets created in the root of the FTP server but it is empty. What's wrong? I already tried to change the ftp mode to BINARY when uploading a PDF file. But the file is also 0 in size.

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

I also only want to upload a bunch of txt files, so the default ascii mode should be fine, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it seems that it is a probem with my firewall. when I deactivate the firewall the file gets written to the ftp with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. The file created but size 0 KB. After setting mode to *passive*, my file successfully transferred to FTP server. In fact there are two things we have to take care while uploading file on FTP server.

1. set file type to binary

   ```
   objFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
   ```
2. set mode to *passive*:

   ```
   objFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set the FileTranserMode to binary too:

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```